# Automatically Resize Page Title

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is it possible to set the a page's title to resize automatically when the browser window is reduced in size, in the same way the rest of a page's content does?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you paste a screenshot, please? so that it's easier to understand the context of your question.

Answer (score 0):

By design, the size of the Page Title is fixed and cannot be resized automatically with the size of the browse.

[image]

Comment: Understood, thank you.

Comment: Hi, AGT2701. Thanks for your reply. Have a nice day!